# variable not incrementing inside the for loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file to change the raw files to wav files and change the file name with a number stored in buffer and increment them.

```
D:
cd Sphinx_UE4_Demo\Plugins\sphinx-ue4\voice_data
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p i=<buffer.txt
for %x in (*.raw) do (
..\sox-14-4-2\sox -r 16k -e signed -b 16 -c 1 %x %i%.wav
set /A i+=1
)
endlocal
```

problem is its not getting incremented, what is the mistake?

So if buffer.txt has 0
then expected output is 0.wav,1.wav,2.wav
but only 0.wav is getting generated

Comment: The problem is `delayed expansion` is required. Please search SO for `delayed expansion` - there are hundreds of articles about it.

Comment: I have applied delayed expansion

Comment: You have not. To access a variable in delayedexpansion mode, you need to use `!var!` in place of `%var%`. You have a second problem - references to the metavariable `x` need a double `%` in batch - but a single `%` direct from the prompt, so `%x` needs to be `%%x` throughout

Comment: thanks its working, I was confused with the prompt mode and the batch file mode.

Comment: common errors - everyone makes them a few times.

Comment: Your problem is not a batch file mode versus cmd prompt mode.  The expansion of variables inside a code block are the same.  Delayed Expansion needs to be enabled and you need to reference them correctly.